# How do I create an array corresponding to the non zero elements of another matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I create an array corresponding to the non zero elements of another matrix in Matlab?

For example, I have a matrix M as shown here:
[image]

In Matlab, I want to create an array that only contains the position of the non-zero elements row-wise like this:

```
Y=[ 1 2 5 6 9 13 17......]
```

Comment: Can't find the exact duplicate right now but you can use `Y = find(x).'`, where `x` is your matrix

Comment: thanks very much ,i can obtain the result using find(x) function. Thanks!

Comment: @Paolo's command gives the position column-wise. If you want them row-wise, you'd have to transpose the matrix first: `find(x.').'`. The second transpose, as suggested by Paolo, is to turn the column vector output of `find` into a row vector. It is the first transpose that is the most important here to get the numbers as you expect them,